# How would I process loop index separately

Tags: python

would like to process different index ranges differently.

````
for i in range(0,10):
        [0,3]:
           print('hello')
        [3,5]:
          print('hi')
        [5,10]:
          print('end')```
````

Comment: Please clarify your question, what you've tried, and what isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reuse the range function

```
  for i in range(0,10):
      if i in range(0,3):
           print('hello')
      if i in range(3,5):
          print('hi')
      if i in range(5,10):
          print('end')
```

However, `0 <= i < 3` performs better, for example

Answer (score 0):

What you need is conditional expressions, read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp).

```
for i in range(0,10):
        if i<3:
           print('hello')
        elif i >=3 and i<=5:
          print('hi')
        else:
          print('end')
```

**Edit:**

This should achieve what you want.

```
def loop_ranges(lb,ub):
    for i in range(lb,ub):
        if i<3:
           print('hello')
        elif i >=3 and i<=5:
          print('hi')
        else:
          print('end')


for i in range(len(list)-2):
   loop_ranges(list[i],list[i+1])
```

Comment: It is  little more complex than that , what I really need is the range to update based of the index

Comment: The range function updates automatically, so for each iteration of `i` the value will be incremented by 1. If you want to control the entire range function, then define a function and take in two parameters for lower-bound and upper-bound of the for loop. You can then make call to this function.

Comment: clarification: the range value are in a list [3,2,5] , so the list process the [0]( range( 0,2))  different from [1] and [2]

Comment: for [0] it should be range(0,3) and [1] -> range(0,2) and [2] -> range(0,5). Am i correct? How do you know your upperbounds and lowerbounds of the loop this way?

Comment: the next range starts where the previews one left of.

Comment: See my update. Functions are your friend when you want to make repeated calls to same code block :)